# Uploading to Amazon s3 undefined property in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I have been following [this](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/uploading-files-to-amazon-s3) tutorial for uploading images to amazon s3 and I have run into a error after choosing a image file from a file picker.

```
post_submit.js:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uploadToAmazonS3' of undefined
at Object.change input[type="file"] (post_submit.js:36)
```

Here is my code

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this error, let me know if you need more of my code, but I think this covers most of it.

**client/templates/posts/post_submit.html**

```
<template name="postSubmit">
    <div class="upload-area">
      <form id="upload">
        <p class="alert alert-success text-center">
          <span>Click or Drag a File Here to Upload</span>
          <input type="file">
        </p>
      </form>
      {{> files}}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
  </form>
</template>
```

**client/template/posts/post_submit.js**

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
  'change input[type="file"]' ( event, template ) {
    Modules.client.uploadToAmazonS3( { event: event, template: template } );
  }
});
```

**both/modules/_modules.js**

```
Modules      = {};
Modules.both = {};
```

**client/modules/_modules.js**

```
Modules.client = {};
```

**server/modules/_modules.js**

```
Modules.server = {};
```

**client/modules/upload_to_amazon_s3.js**

```
let template;

let _getFileFromInput = ( event ) => event.target.files[0];

let _setPlaceholderText = ( string = "Click or Drag a File Here to Upload" ) => {
  template.find( ".alert span" ).innerText = string;
};

let _addUrlToDatabase = ( url ) => {
  Meteor.call( "storeUrlInDatabase", url, ( error ) => {
    if ( error ) {
      Bert.alert( error.reason, "warning" );
      _setPlaceholderText();
    } else {
      Bert.alert( "File uploaded to Amazon S3!", "success" );
      _setPlaceholderText();
    }
  });
};

let _uploadFileToAmazon = ( file ) => {
  const uploader = new Slingshot.Upload( "uploadToAmazonS3" );

  uploader.send( file, ( error, url ) => {
    if ( error ) {
      Bert.alert( error.message, "warning" );
      _setPlaceholderText();
    } else {
      _addUrlToDatabase( url );
    }
  });
};

let upload = ( options ) => {
  template = options.template;
  let file = _getFileFromInput( options.event );

  _setPlaceholderText( `Uploading ${file.name}...` );
  _uploadFileToAmazon( file );
};

Modules.client.uploadToAmazonS3 = upload;
```

**server/slingshot.js**

```
Slingshot.fileRestrictions( "uploadToAmazonS3", {
  allowedFileTypes: [ "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif" ],
  maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024
});

Slingshot.createDirective( "uploadToAmazonS3", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  bucket: "mrskitson-images",
  acl: "public-read",
  authorize: function () {
    let userFileCount = Files.find( { "userId": this.userId } ).count();
    return userFileCount < 3 ? true : false;
  },
  key: function ( file ) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne( this.userId );
    return user.emails[0].address + "/" + file.name;
  }
});
```

**lib/collections/files.js**

```
Files = new Meteor.Collection( 'files' );

Files.allow({
  insert: function() { return false; },
  update: function() { return false; },
  remove: function() { return false; }
});

Files.deny({
  insert: function(){ return true; },
  update: function(){ return true; },
  remove: function(){ return true; }
});
```

**both/methods/insert/files.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
  storeUrlInDatabase: function( url ) {
    check( url, String );
    Modules.both.checkUrlValidity( url );

    try {
      Files.insert({
        url: url,
        userId: Meteor.userId(),
        added: new Date()
      });
    } catch( exception ) {
      return exception;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Where do you import these modules files?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by import these modules files?

Comment: I mean, could you show the files where you do `import 'lib/modules/...` etc?

Comment: I don't think I do have any import code, this is a working github repo from this tutorial, I've looked through it and don't see any import code, maybe Im blind. https://github.com/themeteorchef/uploading-files-to-amazon-s3/tree/master/code

Answer (score 0):

@anders-kitson You could have saved yourself a bunch of time by reading the error message carefully. It tells you where the problem is:

`post_submit.js:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uploadToAmazonS3' of undefined
at Object.change input[type="file"] (post_submit.js:36)`

Line 36 of post_submit.js

Although the file you showed as post_submit.js is only 5 lines long. If that is the right file, the offending line is probably this:

`Modules.client.uploadToAmazonS3( { event: event, template: template });`

It's trying to tell you that Modules.client is undefined. That is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Um, I did read the error and I know it is caused by that line of code, but I don't know why that line of code is not working, which is the whole reason I posted all my other code.

Answer (score 0):

You know, I've just cloned this git repo and it works for me:

```
> Modules.client
{uploadToAmazonS3: ƒ}
```

I even renamed existing `client/modules/upload-to-amazon.js` to `client/modules/upload_to_amazon_s3.js` to be exactly the same as in your example code.

Perhaps, there is some issue that prevent your file to load? Maybe file ACL don't have `read` permission?